# cannot find nail for send email

Tags: pi-2

I've this script of transmission daemon that send the email:

```
#!/bin/sh

##
##  User-configurable Variables
##

# Where "nail" is installed on your system.
# We need this to actually send the mail, so make sure it's installed
NAIL=/usr/bin/nail

# REQUIRED CHANGE #1: you must set SMTP_SERVER
# http://www.host45.com/resources/ispsmtps.php has a list of ISP's smtp servers
SMTP_SERVER=smtp.gmail.com

# REQUIRED CHANGE #2: you must set your email address.
# option A: change "yourname@yourmail.com" here and remove the leading '#' to
# use a real email address
#TO_ADDR=yourname@yourmail.com
#
# option B: for an SMS message, set your phone number here and remove the
# leading '#' on the PHONENUM line and your phone provider's TO_ADDR line
#PHONENUM="1234567890"
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@message.alltel.com"      # SMS: Alltel
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@txt.att.net"             # SMS: AT&T (formerly Cingular)
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@myboostmobile.com"       # SMS: Boost Mobile
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@sms.mycricket.com"       # SMS: Cricket Wireless
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@messaging.nextel.com"    # SMS: Nextel (Sprint Nextel)
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@messaging.sprintpcs.com" # SMS: Sprint (Sprint Nextel)
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@tmomail.net"             # SMS: T-Mobile
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@vtext.com"               # SMS: Verizon
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@vmobl.com"               # SMS: Virgin Mobile USA
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@txt.bellmobility.ca"     # SMS: Bell Canada
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@cwemail.com"             # SMS: Centennial Wireless
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@csouth1.com"             # SMS: Cellular Sout
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@gocbw.com"               # SMS: Cincinnati Bell
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@mymetropcs.com"          # SMS: Metro PCS 1
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@metropcs.sms.us"         # SMS: Metro PCS 2
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@qwestmp.com"             # SMS: Quest
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@pcs.rogers.com"          # SMS: Rogers
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@tms.suncom.com"          # SMS: Suncom
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@msg.telus.com"           # SMS: Telus
#TO_ADDR="$PHONENUM@email.uscc.net"          # SMS: U.S. Cellular

###
###  Send the mail...
###

SUBJECT="Download completato!"
FROM_ADDR="transmission@localhost.localdomain"
TMPFILE=`mktemp -t transmission.XXXXXXXXXX`
echo "Transmission ha terminato il download di \"$TR_TORRENT_NAME\" on $TR_TIME_LOCALTIME" >$TMPFILE
$NAIL -v -S from="$FROM_ADDR" -S smtp -s "$SUBJECT" -S smtp=$SMTP_SERVER "$TO_ADDR" < $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

when I execute it I get:

> /usr/bin/nail: not found

I tried to install `apt-get install nail`

but I get:

> script nail has no candidate

how can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

nail is no longer packaged by that name in Debian, but you may find s-nail can do what you need in a familiar way. (I don't know what transmission is doing with email here so I can't promise it's going to work.)

Try an apt-get install of s-nail, which is a descendent of nail. If nail is still not found in the script, just change the line in the script to read

> NAIL=/usr/bin/s-nail

You can find a project home for s-nail at https://git.sdaoden.eu/cgit/s-nail.git

Good luck!

---

PS: Here is a transcript of me retrieving s-nail from a current (Apr 2018) install of Rasbian Stretch.

root@psychic:/mnt/keeper/backups/psychic/etc# apt-get install ssmtp s-nail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgnutls-openssl27
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgnutls-openssl27 s-nail ssmtp
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 551 kB of archives.
After this operation, 914 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://raspbian.mirror.colo-serv.net/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgnutls-openssl27 armhf 3.5.8-5+deb9u3 [182 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.mirror.colo-serv.net/raspbian stretch/main armhf s-nail armhf 14.8.16-1 [315 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.mirror.colo-serv.net/raspbian stretch/main armhf ssmtp armhf 2.64-8 [54.2 kB]
Fetched 551 kB in 1s (427 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnutls-openssl27:armhf.
(Reading database ... 34436 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgnutls-openssl27_3.5.8-5+deb9u3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnutls-openssl27:armhf (3.5.8-5+deb9u3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package s-nail.
Preparing to unpack .../s-nail_14.8.16-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking s-nail (14.8.16-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ssmtp.
Preparing to unpack .../ssmtp_2.64-8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking ssmtp (2.64-8) ...
Setting up s-nail (14.8.16-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Setting up libgnutls-openssl27:armhf (3.5.8-5+deb9u3) ...
Setting up ssmtp (2.64-8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...

Comment: I get: cannot found the packages s-nail